# cannot deploy zip to Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I'm trying to check a zip file (created by an external process) into Nexus using mvn deploy:deploy-file.

When I run from the command line (Win), everything works and I can see the pom and zip in my snapshot repo. However If I use a maven job in Jenkins to do the same I'm getting the following error :

[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: zip @ line 6, column 13

pom looks like :

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
<artifactId>testApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>zip</packaging>
</project>
```

mvn command is :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=d:\testApp.pom -Dfile=d:\testapp.zip
-DrepositoryId=snapshots 
-Durl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
```

If I was using the wrong packaging, why does it work for one and not the other ?

Comment: You're using a Windows slave as well?

Comment: Making packaging `pom` and use the build-helper-maven-plugin and attach the zip file to the project during the run...

Comment: No slaves, everything is running on the one box.
will look at the other plugin, but I don't understand why it works outside of Jenkins ? Surely all Jenkins is doing is calling the same goals etc.

Answer (score 0):

This page describes the <packaging> tag: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates

It says, and I quote:

> The current core packaging values are: pom, jar, maven-plugin, ejb, war, ear, rar, par.

Additional plugins can add additional packaging types when they modify the lifecycle.

This information applies to the  tag in the pom.

**Possible solution:** If you comment out or remove the <packaging>zip</packaging> it will stop failing with an error message.

This means when you can use the command with one more -D option

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file ... -Dfile=somefile.zip -Dpackaging=zip
```

to publish a file to a maven repository like Nexus or Artifactory. Maven will not complain because its only checking the tag for validity.

**However**, if you are doing anything else with Maven and that anything requires you to set the packaging type, you will need to find another solution.